# Functions for manipulating nested lists

Tags: python

1) If I do:

```
tablero = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' 
'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' 
', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
def dibujar_cruz():
    x = 0
    a = "X"
    size = len(tablero)
    for row in tablero:
        tablero[x][x] = a  
        tablero[x][size-x-1]=a        
        x += 1      
    for l in tablero:
        print (" ".join(l))
dibujar_cruz()
```

I obtain:

[an star of size 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IklQQ.jpg)

2) But if the function "dibujar_cruz()" takes the initial nested list from another function like this:

```
tablero =[]
def construir_tablero():
    size =int(input("Which is the size of the nested lists? "))
    col=[]
    for x in range (size):
        col .append(" ")
    for b in range(size):
        tablero.append(col)
    return (tablero)
print (construir_tablero())
def dibujar_cruz():
    x = 0
    size = len(tablero)
    for row in tablero:
        row [x]= "X"
        row[size-x-1]="X"
        x += 1    
    for l in tablero:
        print (" ".join(l))
dibujar_cruz()
```

I obtain:

[Square obtained calling the two functions consecutively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r45Ly.jpg)

When I expected to have the same star as in point 1).

3) If I define a third function that calls the two first ones:

```
def construir_cruz():
    construir_tablero()
    dibujar_cruz()
construir_cruz()
```

I expected to obtain the same star as in 1) but I obtain an Error:

> ... row[size-x-1]="X"
>
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

The results in 2) and 3) were unexpected for me. Why did I obtain them?

Comment: In `construir_tablero` you append a reference to the same list repeatedly to the parent list (the "table"). Since your table actually contains only one row, just many times, you fill it with X completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stressed by Ilja Everilä in comment, your array `tablero` contains X copies of the same array `col`,  but this is a copy by reference, not by value. Therefore, each time you modify one of the columns in `tablero`, the change appears in every columns.

The solution is to copy `col` by value. Just change:

```
tablero.append(col)
```

to:

```
tablero.append(col[:])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in point 3) is that when repeating the function

```
construir_cruz()
```

it already has a *tablero* in memory. 
Changing the position of the definition of *tablero* from:

```
tablero = []    
def construir_tablero():
    size =int(input("Which is the size of the nested lists? "))
    col=[]
    for x in range (size):
        col .append(" ")
    for b in range(size):
        tablero.append(col)
   return (tablero)
```

to

```
def construir_tablero():
    tablero =[]
    size =int(input("Which is the size of the nested lists? "))
    col=[]
    for x in range (size):
        col .append(" ")
    for b in range(size):
        tablero.append(col)
    return (tablero)
```

solves the problem, because it redefines *tablero* in each call.